# Why volatile read always uncontended?

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, volatile, contention

Quote from book java concurrency in practice:

> The performance cost of synchronization comes from several sources.
>   The visibility guarantees provided by synchronized and volatile may
>   entail using special instructions called memory barriers that can
>   flush or invalidate caches, flush hardware write buffers, and stall
>   execution pipelines. Memory barriers may also have indirect
>   performance consequences because they inhibit other compiler
>   optimizations; most operations cannot be reordered with memory
>   barriers. When assessing the performance impact of synchronization, it
>   is important to distinguish between contended and uncontended
>   synchronization. The synchronized mechanism is optimized for the
>   uncontended case (**volatile is always uncontended**), and at this
>   writing, the performance cost of a "fastͲpath" uncontended
>   synchronization ranges from 20 to 250 clock cycles for most systems.

Can you clarify this more clear? 
What if I have huge amount threads which read volaile variable ?

Can you provide contention definition?

Is there tool to meausure contention? In which values it is measures?

Answer (score 4):

> Can you clarify this more clear?

That is one dense paragraph that touches a lot of topics. Which topic or topics specifically are you asking for clarification? Your question is too broad to answer satisfactorily. Sorry.

Now, if you question is specific to **uncontended** synchronization, it means that threads within a JVM do not have to block, get unblocked/notified and then go back to a blocked state.

Under the hood, the JVM uses hardware specific memory barriers that ensure

1. A `volatile` field is always read and written to/from main memory, not from the CPU/core cache, and
2. Your thread will not block/unblock to access it.

There is no contention. When you use a synchronized block OTH, all your threads are in a blocked state except one, the one reading whatever data is being protected by the synchronized block.

Let's call that thread, the one accessing the synchronized data, *thread A*.

Now, here is the kicker, when *thread A* is done with the data and exists the synchronized block, this causes the JVM to *wake up* all the other threads that are/were waiting for *thread A* to exit the synchronization block.

They all wake up (and that is expensive CPU/memory wise). And they all race trying to get a hold of the synchronization block.

Imagine a whole bunch of people trying to exit a crowded room through a tiny room. Yep, like that, that's how threads act when they try to grab a synchronization lock.

But only one gets it and gets in. All the others go back to sleep, kind of, in what is called a *blocked state*. This is also expensive, resource wise.

So every time one of the threads exists a synchronization block, all the other threads go crazy (best mental image I can think of) to get access to it, one gets it, and all the others go back to a blocked state.

That's what makes synchronized blocks expensive. Now, here is the caveat: It used to be very expensive pre JDK 1.4. That's 17 years ago. Java 1.4 started seeing some improvements (2003 IIRC).

Then Java 1.5 introduced even greater improvements in 2005, 12 years ago, which made synchronized blocks less expensive.

It is important to keep such things in mind. There is a lot of outdated information out there.

> What if I have huge amount threads which read volaile variable ?

It wouldn't matter that much in terms of correctness. A `volatile` field will always show a consistent value regardless of the number of threads.

Now, if you have a very large number of threads, performance can suffer because of context switches, memory utilization, etc (and not necessarily and/or primarily because of accessing a `volatile` field.

> Can you provide contention definition?

Please don't take it the wrong way, but if you are asking that question, I'm afraid you are not fully prepared to use a book like the one you are reading.

You will need a more basic introduction to concurrency, and contention specifically.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_contention

Best regards.

Comment: Good answer dude.  You talk about `synchronized` blocks but not enough about the lock overhead.  It's implied with the blocking discussion but it would be good to mention the performance implications of even holding and then releasing a synchronized lock.  Also when a thread exits the synchronized block only 1 thread is unblocked, not all.

Comment: Also, "all the other threads go crazy (best mental image I can think of) to get access to it" is wrong.  When a thread unlocks the lock, the first thread (if any) in the queue waiting for the lock is given the lock.  All threads don't awaken and fight it out.

Comment: @Gray when you say it's wrong, are you talking from the perspective of `synchronized` or `java.util.concurrent` classes. `java.util.concurrent` classes use CLH locking which is a queue based locking, but I'm not sure and doubt about queues in `synchronized`. If `synchronized` used queues, why is it unfair and why does it cause starvation?

Comment: Who says it is unfair @SaptarshiBasu?  It's up to the OS implementation of course but I know of none that cause starvation.  It typically is FIFO.